# Visual Studio Tools for Unity (旧UnityVS)の入手方法を教えてください

Tags: unity3d, visual-studio

最近 Visual Studio Tools for Unity というツールがあることを知りました。
どこからダウンロードできますか？

Comment: 質問者が質問者なだけありプロモーションに感じられます。
このようなプロモーションはむしろタグWikiに直接書いていただいたほうが歓迎されるかと思います。

Answer (score 4):

[Visual Studio Tools for Unityのドキュメント](http://aka.ms/vstudocj)からも辿れますが、下記のリンクをご利用ください。

Visual Studio Tools for Unity (無料)
[Visual Studio 2010 用](http://aka.ms/vstu2010)
[Visual Studio 2012 用](http://aka.ms/vstu2012)
[Visual Studio 2013 用](http://aka.ms/vstu2013)
[Visual Studio 2015 Preview 用](http://aka.ms/vstu2015)